# Can't boot from Dell Ubuntu ISO

Tags: 16.04, boot-repair

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (vanilla) om Dell XPS 13 9360.

I downloaded the recovery *dell-bto-xenial-dino2-mlk-A00-iso-20161021-0.iso* from Dell and, like here http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/os-applications/f/4613/t/19501016?pi22229=2, I cannot create a bootable USB stick from that.

Is there a solution for that? my laptop came with Windows and I have some performance issues. I have UEFI and secure boot disabled.

Best,

Comment: 1. If you give us a link, where we can download that iso file, we can test it. Otherwise we can only guess about the problem: for example, if it is not a hybrid iso file, it will work when burned to a DVD disk, but not when cloned to a USB drive. However, it might work when extracted to a USB drive with some tool; 2. You can ask at Dell, they should be able to advice how to use that iso file.

Comment: thanks @sudodus, I did call Dell and they said "uh? what?"

Comment: If you cannot give us a link, maybe you can try yourself. You could start making a backup copy of your iso file, to avoid problem it the file would be damaged. Then you can try some methods to make a USB boot drive from it and try to boot. Start trying according to these links (and links from them), https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/iso2usb and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/isohybrid and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick

Comment: It is also possible (probable), that you have better luck with the new (still developing) version Ubuntu Artful Aardvark, to be released during this month (October 2017) as 17.10. It comes with a new linux kernel and new hardware drivers, that are more likely to work with your new computer and its high end graphics. See these links, 'final:' http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/383/builds and 'beta:' http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/382/builds

Comment: @sudodus after reading a lot one option is to use `dell-recovery` but that's old and has signatures problems, but there is a new version here https://github.com/dell/dell-recovery ... I will try it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67296/discussion-between-sudodus-and-pachamaltese).